# Adding missing data conditional on grouping variables within data frame

Tags: r, missing-data

Here's a four column df. Site, Visit, Ind(ividual), Obs(erved)

```
site<-c(rep("X",6),rep("Y",8),rep("Z",4))
visit<-c(1,1,2,2,3,3,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,1,1,2,2)
ind<-c(rep(c("a","b"),9))    
obs<-1    
dat<-as.data.frame(cbind(site,visit,ind,obs))
```

In this example I have three sites with unequal visits (X=3, Y=4, Z=2). I would like to add visits for site X and Z that "did not occur" for both individuals (a and b) and have a NA's in the observed column. As in this example:

```
site<-c(rep("X",8),rep("Y",8),rep("Z",8))
visit<-c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4)
ind<-c(rep(c("a","b"),12))    
obs<-c(rep(1,6),NA,NA,rep(1,12),rep(NA,4))    
dat2<-as.data.frame(cbind(site,visit,ind,obs))
```

This is a much simpler version of a very large data set with 500+ sites and 300+ individuals. I'm struggling with a quick way to accomplish what I'm striving for. Simple solutions out there? Thanks.

Also can anyone think of a better title for this post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do as shown below. All possible matches of site, ind, visit are created by `expand.grid()`. Then data is joined to it, which is left outer join that keeps all the expanded values (`all.x = TRUE`)

```
# your data
site<-c(rep("X",6),rep("Y",8),rep("Z",4))
visit<-c(1,1,2,2,3,3,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,1,1,2,2)
ind<-c(rep(c("a","b"),9))
obs <- 1
dat<-as.data.frame(cbind(site,visit,ind,obs))
# all matches of site, ind, visit
site <- c("X", "Y", "Z")
ind <- c("a", "b")
visit <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
grid <- expand.grid(site = site, ind = ind, visit = visit)
# merge - left outer join that keeps all grid values
merge(grid, dat, by = c("site", "ind", "visit"), all.x = TRUE)
   site ind visit  obs
1     X   a     1    1
2     X   a     2    1
3     X   a     3    1
4     X   a     4 <NA>
5     X   b     1    1
6     X   b     2    1
7     X   b     3    1
8     X   b     4 <NA>
9     Y   a     1    1
10    Y   a     2    1
11    Y   a     3    1
12    Y   a     4    1
13    Y   b     1    1
14    Y   b     2    1
15    Y   b     3    1
16    Y   b     4    1
17    Z   a     1    1
18    Z   a     2    1
19    Z   a     3 <NA>
20    Z   a     4 <NA>
21    Z   b     1    1
22    Z   b     2    1
23    Z   b     3 <NA>
24    Z   b     4 <NA>
```